# Push notification in iOS 13 appears and disappears immediately

Tags: notifications, push, ios13, banner, badge

I got the issue that my app sometime don't show push notification at banner of home device.
It (notification & badge) just appears and disappears immediately (after that the badge of App also dismiss). I can not touch it to launch app from banner.
My app works normal in iOS 12 but get issue in iOS 13
Does Everyone get this like me?
Please help me the solution/information if you know.

Thanks all!

Comment: Can you please add code of how you displayed notification ?

Comment: Do you have any notification extensions or push notification handling code that might be executed when a push is delivered?

Comment: After check again, i see when i set content-available is true so the banner and badge appear and disappear immediately. But if i set it to false so the banner and badge appear normal.
I didn't use any notification extension and just handle:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        NotificationHandle.shared.process(userInfo: userInfo)
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30) {
   completionHandler(.newData)
  }
 }